# Angular Route Path components grouped

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

There are four menu space in my UI, One on left top (available only when logged in by official credentials) another in same location  (available to all logged in volunteers), and third one on the right Top (to show notifications, alerts, and application-wide actions), And fourth required on left click on the page(includes some menu on left top ie. mark to send and some new options)

[Routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes)  I could not find group by parameters

Something like this would best describe the solution:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, linkTo:"menu"},
     ...
    {path:"linkup", component:LinkupComponent, linkTo:"menu popup"},

    …
    {path="notify", component:NotifyComponent, linkTo:"appmenu"}
 ]
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why you need routes for all of 4 comp ? you can add comp without any route using master detail/ parent child comp https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Comment: I think what you need here is a router-outlet. Reference: https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#multiple-outlets

Comment: Seems like same entry needs to be posted multiple times { path:"xx", component:XXComponent, outlet:"menu"}, {path:"xx", component:XXComponent, outlet:"popup"} etc.